# Algorithm to find list given dot product and another list

Tags: algorithm, functional-programming, sml

I need to write a function `findL` that takes a list *L*<sub>1</sub> of integers and a desired dot product *n*, and returns a list *L*<sub>2</sub> of nonnegative integers such that *L*<sub>1</sub> · *L*<sub>2</sub> = *n*. (By "dot product" I mean the sum of the pairwise products; for example, [1,2] · [3,4] = 1·3+2·4 = 11.)

So, for example, `findL(11, [1,2])` might return `SOME [3,4]`. If there's no possible list, I return `NONE`.

I'm using a functional language. (Specifically Standard ML, but the exact language isn't so important, I'm just trying to think of an FP algorithm.) What I have written so far:

Let's say I have findL(n, L1):

1. if L1 = [], I return NONE.
2. if L1 = [x] (list of length 1)

   - if (n >= 0 and x > 0 and n mod x = 0), return SOME [n div x]
   - else return NONE
3. If L1 has length greater than 1, I recurse on findL (n, L[1:]). If that returns a list L2, I return [1] concatenated to L2. If the recursive call returns NONE, I did another recursive call on findL (0, L[1:]) and prepended [n div x] to the result if it wasn't NONE. This works on many inputs but are failing on others.

I need to change part 3, but I'm not sure if I have the right idea. I would appreciate any tips!

Comment: False is not a list. Your spec has a type error.

Comment: @melpomene I know, I actually return NONE. If there's a result, I return SOME result (basically using options in SML). I just thought that not a lot of people would know SML so I didn't get into the details and just asked for algorithmic help.

Comment: Your question will probably get more attention if you tag it with a specific programming language.

Comment: @melpomene I did tag functional-programming since "SML" has very little posts, but I tagged that too just in case. Thanks.

Comment: Are the dot product or any of the values in the input list allowed to be negative?

Comment: This is closely related to the [change-making problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem). The difference is that you want *any* result, whereas the change-making problem more specifically seeks the result with the least possible sum.

Comment: This can be rephrased as a knapsack problem which can be solved with dynamic programming (assuming input list values and the dot product are nonnegative).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you need to say that empty lists in the input are always bad (even n = 0 with the list []), I'd recommend returning something different for an empty list based on whether you've reached 0 at the end (everything has been subtracted away) or not, then recurse when receiving any nonempty list rather than special-casing a one-element list.

As far as step three, you need to test **every** possible positive integer multiple of the first element of your input list until they exceed n, not just the first and last. The first non-None value you get is good enough, so you just prepend the multiplier (not the multiple) to the return list. If everything gives you Nones, you return None.

---

I don't know SML, but here's how I'd do it in Haskell:

```hs
import Data.Maybe (isJust, listToMaybe)

-- Find linear combinations of positive integers
solve :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Maybe [Integer]
-- If we've made it to the end with zero left, good!
solve 0 []     = Just []
-- Otherwise, this way isn't the way to go.
solve _ []     = Nothing
-- If one of the elements of the input list is zero, just multiply that element by one.
solve n (0:xs) = case solve n xs of
                      Nothing -> Nothing
                      Just ys -> Just (1:ys)
solve n (x:xs) =   listToMaybe                    -- take first solution if it exists
                 . map (\ (m, Just ys) -> m:ys)   -- put multiplier at front of list
                 . filter (isJust . snd)          -- remove nonsolutions
                 . zip [1 ..]                     -- tuple in the multiplier
                 . map (\ m -> solve (n - m) xs)  -- use each multiple
                 $ [x, x + x .. n]                -- the multiples of x up to n
```

[Here it is solving `11` with `[1, 2]` and `1` with `[1, 2]`](https://ideone.com/J79H8Y#stdout).

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused :/. The algorithm makes perfect sense but I'm not sure how I would code it. I made an edit with my original solution. I need to change the very last NONE case. I know you don't know SML but could you explain what you're doing in the last case a little more? Haskell and SML seem to have similar functions (map, filter, zip..) but I'm not sure how to create the multiples list (x, x+x, ...). In this line : map (\ m -> solve (n - m) xs)  $ [x, x + x .. n], are you using each x, x+x, etc.. in place of m?

Comment: The code you added to your question is pretty good, except that you need to test **all** the multiples of `x`, not just `x` and `n` (if `n` is a multiple of `x`). You need `x`, `2*x`, `3*x`, *etc*. until they get up past `n`.

Comment: Yes, `x`, `x+x`, `x+x+x` and so on are used in place of `m` in the bottom `map`.

Comment: You can make a second function that makes that list at the bottom: `multiplesUpTo n x = go n x x where go n x m = if m > n then [] else m:go n x (m + x)`. Then, you'd just say `multiplesUpTo n x` in your original function.